# Angular unit test anonimous arrow function

Tags: angular, unit-testing

How can i cover all statements of this function?

[image]

So far i have writen below spec, but cannot figured out how to cover all statements.

[image]

Comment: The code you've shown never calls the inner `deleteSection` function, it's only executing the first line and initializes `const deleteSection`. However, it is never being called.

Comment: Yes, its true, but how can i call and test the inner function that is attached to a const variable?

Comment: Please post complete code for unit under test. This insufficient information to answer the question. Simplest would be to not have it be an inner function. Move it outside and unit test on its own.

Comment: Any code you can share on unit testing arrow functions?